# close button isn't working on popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've made a popup window by searching on google. I don't have too much knowledge about web development. By ready and experimenting multiple website pages I've made a Modal for my website. I've set everything in that popup as my per needs and it works fine except the close button.

Can you please be kind to take a look on my following code and guide me how can I make close button working?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#dialog-message").css("display", "block");
  jQuery("#close-btn").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('#dialog-message').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700');
.exit_popup-sec {
  width: 915px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 34px 62px 60px 62px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #ffff00;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
  margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
  ;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff6c00', endColorstr='#ff0000', GradientType=0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.popup-graybox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 99999;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.exit_popup-sec .booknow-popup-clsbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: -7px;
  top: -14px;
  border: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exit_popup-sec .booknow-popup-clsbtn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #252525;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:815px) {
  .exit_popup-sec {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content {
    padding: 20px 30px 50px 30px;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}

.ui-widget-content a {
  color: #72d6d6;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



  <div id="dialog-message">
    <section class="popup-graybox">
      <div class="exit_popup-sec">
        <div class="exit_popup-content" style="background: #252525 url(https://pakxchange.com/pop-up/webmoney.png) no-repeat right 0;">
          <h2 data-edit="text">Webmoney Account Verification</h2>
          <h3 data-edit="text">We are the only Country Representative of <a href="https://passport.wmtransfer.com/asp/Reglist.asp">Webmoney Payment Network</a> in Pakistan. We verify webmoney users, their documents and issue them Initial &amp; Personal passports. <a href="https://pakxchange.com/sources/payment/NewWMZ.php">READ MORE</a></h3>
          <button class="getoffer-btn" type="submit"><a href="https://passport.wmtransfer.com/asp/certview.asp?wmid=085789787326">Our Certified Webmoney Account</a></button>
          <button class="booknow-popup-clsbtn close-btn close-btn">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: here is my website link where I want to show this popup modal: https://pakxchange.com/

Comment: You don't have have any id with name `close-btn` its class i.e : `.close-btn` change that .

Comment: hello Thank you for the comment:
I've added another div with this name close-btn

under dialog-message div but it still not working .. can you please check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#dialog-message").css("display", "block");
      jQuery("#popup_close_btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parents('#dialog-message').hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700');
    .exit_popup-sec {
      width: 915px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content {
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 34px 62px 60px 62px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.52);
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      color: #ffff00;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 28px;
      width: 400px;
      float: left;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
      margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
      color: #FFF;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 400px;
      float: left;
      line-height: 26px;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn {
      width: 50%;
      padding: 20px 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      clear: both;
      float: left;
      border: 0px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #fff;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
      ;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #337ab7 1%, #4f4fe8 100%);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff6c00', endColorstr='#ff0000', GradientType=0);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn:hover {
      background: #ff0000;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content .getoffer-btn:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    .popup-graybox {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 99999;
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .booknow-popup-clsbtn {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 18px;
      width: 28px;
      height: 28px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #FFF;
      position: absolute;
      right: -7px;
      top: -14px;
      border: 0px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .exit_popup-sec .booknow-popup-clsbtn:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: #252525;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:815px) {
      .exit_popup-sec {
        width: 95%;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content {
        padding: 20px 30px 50px 30px;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
        font-size: 80px;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
        width: 350px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h2 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .exit_popup-sec .exit_popup-content h3 {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 30px;
      }
    }

    .ui-widget-content a {
      color: #72d6d6;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



      <div id="dialog-message">
        <section class="popup-graybox">
          <div class="exit_popup-sec">
            <div class="exit_popup-content" style="background: #252525 url(https://pakxchange.com/pop-up/webmoney.png) no-repeat right 0;">
              <h2 data-edit="text">Webmoney Account Verification</h2>
              <h3 data-edit="text">We are the only Country Representative of <a href="https://passport.wmtransfer.com/asp/Reglist.asp">Webmoney Payment Network</a> in Pakistan. We verify webmoney users, their documents and issue them Initial &amp; Personal passports. <a href="https://pakxchange.com/sources/payment/NewWMZ.php">READ MORE</a></h3>
              <button class="getoffer-btn" type="submit"><a href="https://passport.wmtransfer.com/asp/certview.asp?wmid=085789787326">Our Certified Webmoney Account</a></button>
              <button class="booknow-popup-clsbtn close-btn close-btn" id="popup_close_btn">X</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section>
```

You are refering to close button by id, and you have not assigned any id to the close button. Please assign the id to close button. it should work.

If you want to have to use  css selector way to fix this:
$(".booknow-popup-clsbtn").

Comment: it's not a Typo issue, it was CSS selector issue. The css selector was wrong in the question.

Comment: Thanks both of you .. can you please tell me how can I make this close button work? whether by assigning a div ID or without div id ..?

Comment: @muqaddasshahzad I have edited my answer to have CSS selector for your close button use that insted of   jQuery("#close-btn")

Comment: thank you can you please correct my script and paste here ?
or at least tell me where I can place this:
$(".booknow-popup-clsbtn")

Comment: @muqaddasshahzad  Edited the answer to show how to use.